# Is it possible to add tooltip the expand/collapse button from the jQGrid header?

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to add tooltip to the expand/collapse button o[JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=629) so that it can change when expanded and vice versa ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the documentation for the control but if not i just inspect it and collapse button html is

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span>
```

and expand is

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-s"></span>
```

so you can get the element by jquery and append what ever kind of html elements you want